# laravel billing stripe alternative

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel for a website. I need all the features provided by laravel cashier but I cannot use Stripe as it is not supported in India.

Is there an alternative that can be used directly with laravel cashier package? Is there a way I can use Stripe although it's not supported in India?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately Laravel 5 cachier is built on stripe Api in almost all functions like subscription and plans and recurring billing and discounts 
so you cannot use it with another payment gateway without heavy customizations

Answer (score 0):

Use PayUMoney or Paytm which are Indian Payment Gateway.

Comment: Yes but then it involves writing all the code from scratch.And for recurring payments and memberships we cant use the normal gateways.